# How to fix "Closure may outlive the current function"

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

I've this code:

```
pub fn find_saddle_points(input: &[Vec<u64>]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
  let mut row_max: Vec<HashSet<usize>> = vec![HashSet::new(); input.len()];
  let mut col_min: Vec<HashSet<usize>> = vec![HashSet::new(); input[0].len()];
  ...
  row_max.iter().enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(row, cols)| {
        cols.iter()
            .filter(|c| col_min[**c].contains(&row))
            .map(|c| (row, *c))
    })
    .collect()
}
```

Compilation fails.

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `row`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:48:21
   |
48 |             .filter(|c| col_min[**c].contains(&row))
   |                     ^^^                        --- `row` is borrowed here
   |                     |
   |                     may outlive borrowed value `row`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:47:9
   |
47 | /         cols.iter()
48 | |             .filter(|c| col_min[**c].contains(&row))
49 | |             .map(|c| (row, *c))
   | |_______________________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `row` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
48 |             .filter(move |c| col_min[**c].contains(&row))
   |                     ++++

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `row`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:49:18
   |
49 |             .map(|c| (row, *c))
   |                  ^^^  --- `row` is borrowed here
   |                  |
   |                  may outlive borrowed value `row`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:47:9
   |
47 | /         cols.iter()
48 | |             .filter(|c| col_min[**c].contains(&row))
49 | |             .map(|c| (row, *c))
   | |_______________________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `row` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
49 |             .map(move |c| (row, *c))
   |                  ++++
```

I can use `move` in the `map` since no one uses `row` after it, but I can't use `move` in the `filter` since `col_min` has type `Vec<HashSet<usize>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture something by reference in a `move` closure, create a reference outside of the closure and then use that reference in the closure; the reference will be moved into the closure instead of the value it references.

```
  row_max.iter().enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(row, cols)| {
        // Shadow col_min with a reference to the outer variable.  The closure
        // will capture this reference instead of the col_min value above.
        let col_min = &col_min;
        cols.iter()
            .filter(move |c| col_min[**c].contains(&row))
            .map(move |c| (row, *c))
    })
    .collect()
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=312d9dea73fabf1c6e8598eca2a11063))

Comment: Thanks! I found that using a `collect` works too `cols.iter().filter(|c| col_min[**c].contains(&row)).map(|c| (row, *c)).collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>()`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Sure, but that's super inefficient because you're collecting a new Vec for each flatmap iteration, before finally collecting them all into a bigger Vec. That will require at least twice the Vec memory usage (more counting unused capacity), an additional allocation per flatmap iteration (possibly more allocations to grow the intermediate Vecs as necessary), and _at minimum_ twice the number of memcpys (more when the intermediate Vecs reallocate).